# Parsing data from Kafka in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am just getting started on Apache Flink (Scala API), my issue is following:
I am trying to stream data from Kafka into Apache Flink based on one example from the Flink site:

```
val stream =
  env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09("testing", new SimpleStringSchema() , properties))
```

Everything works correctly, the stream.print() statement displays the following on the screen:

2018-05-16 10:22:44 AM|1|11|-71.16|40.27

I would like to use a case class in order to load the data, I've tried using

```
flatMap(p=>p.split("|"))
```

but it's only splitting the data one character at a time.

Basically the expected results is to be able to populate 5 fields of the case class as follows

```
  field(0)=2018-05-16 10:22:44 AM
  field(1)=1
  field(2)=11
  field(3)=-71.16 
  field(4)=40.27
```

but it's now doing:

```
   field(0) = 2
   field(1) = 0
   field(3) = 1
   field(4) = 8
```

etc...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Frank

Comment: What do you mean with "splitting the data one character at a time". Maybe you could give an example of the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I've edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `String.split`. If you call it with a `String`, then the method expects it to be a regular expression. Thus, `p.split("\\|")` would be the correct regular expression for your input data. Alternatively, you can also call the `split` variant where you specify the separating character `p.split('|')`. Both solutions should give you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you so much, I truly appreciate your helping a newbie.